# Implementing OAuth Provider in Delphi

Tags: delphi, oauth, restful-authentication

I've developed a REST web service and I want to implement an OAuth Service Provider for authenticating, primarily, two-legged OAuth requests. Could anyone please point me to an implementation of an OAuth Service Provider created in Delphi. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used this [OAUTH for Delphi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oauthdelphi/), but I hear it works.  You can read some more about it in the [creator's blog](http://chuckbeasley.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/using-oauth-for-delphi/).
[image]

Comment: Seems to be stalled, no new commit since 2009, doesn'it ?

Comment: Plus the question was asking for a OAuth Service Provider, while the references library only implements the Consumer (client) part.